# Boundary of the boundary of an oriented compact manifold-with-corners

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold, manifolds-with-boundary

Suppose I have an oriented, compact manifold-with-corners $M$ (see Jack Lee’s *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, pages 417-419). It is not hard to see (using the results of these pages) that its boundary $\partial M$ can be written as a finite union $\partial M=\bigcup_{i=1}^n H_i$, where each $H_i$ is a manifold-with-corners. $M$ being oriented, each $H_i$ is oriented as well via the induced orientation. That is, each $H_i$ is an oriented, compact manifold-with-corners, and hence its boundary can be decomposed as a finite union of manifolds-with-corners as well. We can thus write $\partial H_i=\bigcup_{j=1}^m D_{i,j}$, where each $D_{i,j}$ is an oriented, compact manifold-with-corners.

We can take the free abelian group freely generated by $\{D_{i,j}\}$, where we identify $D_{i_0,j_0}$ with $-D_{i_1,j_1}$ if the two are the same manifold (i.e., the same subset of $M$) but with reversed orientations. We may then consider the sum $\sum_{i,j} D_{i,j}$, which may be considered as the “boundary of the boundary” of $M$. Is it necessarily zero?

> In other words: is it necessarily true that $\{D_{i,j}\}$ can be written as a union of pairs, where each pair consists of the same manifold-with-corners, only with reversed orientation?

Comment: You did not explain how you decomposed the boundary of $M$, what is the difference between pieces called $H$ and the ones called $D$, etc. I suggest you see work out a cube as an example. If you do everything correctly, you will get that boundary of the boundary is zero.

Comment: For $M$ of dimensions $n$ if you define corners as local pieces like $[0,\infty)^k\times\mathbb R^{n-k}$ for $k>1$ then i think that you can flatten each corner to $M'$, and locally get a ball containing a star with $k$ $n-2$-dimensional branches. Globally this gives a union of $n-2$-simplices which "triangulate" $M$ -eg a sum of 4 triangles in a filled tetrahedron-, and the oriented sum of those cycles, $BoB$, is in homology the boundary of the fundamental class of $\partial M$ which is $0$. Then $H_*(\partial M')\cong H_*(\partial M)$ and the sum you described maps to $BoB$. -I think.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I forgot a crucial symbol, and so my question didn't make sense: the $D_{i,j}$ consist of the boundaries of the $H_i$'s, and are so the "boundary of the boundary" of $M$. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: @plm I am not sure if I understand, so I'm not sure if this works... My guess would be that there is a counter-example, though.

Comment: Hi @Cronus; ok. It may depend on the definition of manifold with corners and whether you can homeomorphically/homotopically smooth out the corners. I'll try to check Lee's book.

Comment: [1/2] @Cronus, i deleted my previous comment, i had not read Lee's book well. He asks in exercise 16.18 to prove that an orthant $\bar{\mathbb R}^n_+$ is homeomorphic to a half-space $\mathbb H^n$. This implies that the boundary points of $M$ map in charts to boundary points of $\mathbb H^n$, thus we see locally that $\partial M$ has empty boundary. I assumed that what you define as "boundary of boundary" is the set $C$ of corner points of $\partial M$. And i think the proof sketch above works.

Comment: [2/2] The points where in charts only 2 coordinates vanish are boundary points of a decomposition of $\partial M$ into maximal submanifolds with corners $\partial M=\bigcup_i M_i$. Each $M_i$ has dimension $n-1$. Denote by $B$ the set of such points, and $B_{i,j}\subseteq B$ the connected components of noncorner points of $\partial M_i$. The closure $\bar B_{i,j}$ is equal to exactly one other $\bar B_{i',j'}$, with $i\neq i'$, with $M_i$ and $M_i'$ yielding opposite orientations on $\bar B_{i,j}$. The oriented sum of such closures of components corresponds to the sum above.